# How could I get the coordinates of the circumscribed circle giving the 3 points coords?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

I have the coordinates of 3 points through which, a circle should pass . Having the coordinates of the points in 3D, how could I have the coordinates of the center of circumscribed circle ?
Also: if one of the points has some deviations and causes a circumscribed circle couldn't pass through the 3 points, is there a way to determine the required coordinates of the third point in a way that the circle could be constructed to find the deviation in space ?

[image]

Comment: Three noncolinear points always define a unique plane and a unique circle within that plane. “Deviations” won’t prevent this.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Cartesian_coordinates_from_cross-_and_dot-products for one method.

Comment: The image is not to scale and shows a lie, the drawing contradict the stated side lengths,
Shown sides are almost all equial, $a\approx b$ and is much less than $2b$.
Use a proper tool, draw it accurately and you will see the problem.
This kind of a trick is sometimes used in olympiad questions.

Comment: @g.kov These are the XY coordinates of the points : A( 0 , 60 ) , B (-60, 0 ), 
C(0, -60 )

Comment: This case 
is completely different from the one you mentioned before.
Points $A=(0,60),B=(-60,0),C=(0,-60)$ indeed make an isosceles triangle
(half of the square),
but in this case the side lengths are $b=120$, $a=c=60\times\sqrt2\approx 84.85$.
And the center of circumscribed circle is calculated properly:
$O=(0,0)$, as expected.

Comment: @g.kov you are totally right ! I was mixing up the distances from the mid point of the side with 120 length. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This formula for the center $O$
of a circle 
is suitable for both 2d and 3d:

\begin{align}
O&=
A\cdot \frac{a^2\,(b^2+c^2-a^2)}{((b+c)^2-a^2)(a^2-(b-c)^2)}
\\
&+B\cdot \frac{b^2\,(a^2+c^2-b^2)}{((a+c)^2-b^2)(b^2-(a-c)^2)}
\\
&+C\cdot \frac{c^2\,(b^2+a^2-c^2)}{((b+a)^2-c^2)(c^2-(b-a)^2)}
,
\end{align}

where $A,B,C$ are the coordinates (2d or 3d) of the three given points,
and $a,b,c$ are the side length of the corresponding $\triangle ABC$.

As for deviations of the location of one point,
I can see one specific unstable configuration
when e.g. $B\approx C$. For $B=C$ the center is $O=\tfrac12(B+C)$,
but any small deviation of the location of, say, the point $C$
along the line $AB$ pushes $O$ to infinity, so you can check
such a condition and react somewhat reasonably.

Comment: Thank you very much, but if B(xb,yb) , what should I put for B or C in the equation ? xb or yb ? how do I put both ? didn't get

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti: Well, in the given formula 
$O,A,B,C$ represent the points, that is,
a pairs 
$(O_x,O_y)$, $(A_x,A_y)$, $(B_x,B_y)$, $(C_x,C_y)$
in 2d or the triplets
$(O_x,O_y,O_z)$,
$(A_x,A_y,A_z)$,
$(B_x,B_y,B_z)$,$(C_x,C_y,C_z)$,
and $a,b,c$ are the corresponding side lengths (real numbers)
of $\triangle ABC$.
You can look at the formula as a compact way to represent 
two (in 2d) or three (in 3d) expressions, that is, 

$O_x=A_x\cdot(\cdots)+B_x\cdot(\cdots)+C_x\cdot(\cdots)$,

$O_y=A_y\cdot(\cdots)+B_y\cdot(\cdots)+C_y\cdot(\cdots)$,

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: There is a problem : if a= 2b = 2c , then this formula does not work

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti: Condition $a=2\,b = 2\,c$,
means that $A,B,C$ are on the same line,
and $O=\infty$.

Comment: No I mean an Isosceles triangle with the biggest side twice the others

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti: Yes, you are talking about a so-called degenerate triangle $ABC$ 
with $|AB|=c$, $|BC|=a=2c$, $|CA|=b=c$, $A\in BC$, $A=\tfrac12\,(B+C)$.
The area of this degenerate triangle  is zero, and 
circumradius is $\infty$, location of the center of the circumscribed circle is undefined.

Comment: no ! it's not possilbe to be zero ! it's an existing triangle, I upload an image of it to the question !

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti: Look: $\cos\angle ABC=\frac{a^2-b^2+c^2}{2ac}$,
if $b=c$ we have $\cos\angle ABC=\frac a{2b}$,
if also $a=2b$ we have $\cos\angle ABC=\frac {2b}{2b}=1$,
hence, $\angle ABC=0$
$\triangle ABC$ is degenerate, its area is zero, $\dots$

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti: Or, even simpler, $b+c=2b=a$, triangle is degenerate,
since for a valid triangle we must have $b+c>a$.

Comment: thank you , but I was slower than you to upload the image of the triangle ! there's something I don't understand

Answer (score 1):

If you have the coordinates three points $A, B,$ and $C,$ you can find the perpendicular bisectors of $AB, AC,$ and $BC$ and then you can find the point of concurrency of the three perpendicular bisectors, which will be the center of the unique circle on which $A, B,$ and $C$ fall.