# Computing $\iint_S (y+z)\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z+(z+x)\mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}x+(x+y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Computing $$I=\iint_S (y+z)\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z+(z+x)\mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}x+(x+y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y,$$ where $S$ is the upper side of the plane $x+y+z=1$ located inside the interior of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1$.

I have tried two methods: First, I attempted to close the surface and use Divergence Theorem, but the integral over the sphere surface was also difficult to calculate. Second, I directly projected the integral onto the $xy$-plane, but the projected surface became an ellipse, and I am not familiar with handling such cases.

I wonder if there are any other solutions available.

---

I found a stupid mistake in my second solution. I've corrected it and wrote an answer.

Comment: The ellipse sounds promising, could you include your work up until that?

Comment: What do you mean by "the *upper side of* the plane"? Isn't $S$ just the intersection of that plane with the unit ball?

Comment: @Lorago Yes, I think it was $\iint_D (1-x-y) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$ where $D$ is $x^2+y^2+xy-x-y \leq 0$.

Comment: Could you edit it into your question?

Comment: A bit more details would be appreciated. Would computing that integral over the ellipse answer your question? Or is there more you need to compute at that point?

Comment: @Anne Bauval the plane has orientation.

Comment: Since $\nabla\cdot(y+z, x+z, x+y) = 0$, you can use Stokes' theorem to turn this into a line integral of some vector field around the boundary of $S$.

Comment: Probably far more work than is required, but you could rotate the system by [$\sec^{-1}\sqrt3$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=angle+between+planes+x%2By%2Bz%3D1+and+z%3D0) about the vector $\pm\langle-1,1,0\rangle$ to make the plane parallel to $z=0$, so the projection is a circle centered at the origin.

Comment: To finish off @user170231's idea, you can get the radius and center of the circle by using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3737949/the-plane-xyz-1-intersects-the-curve-x2y2z2-1-at-a-circle-c-find-th) answer, then just apply the transformation to the center and you have your new circle to integrate over

Comment: @Lorago I've added more details about my approach.

Comment: Change variables in your last integral to get it to an integral over a circle, then parameterize. Pretty sure that should do the trick

Comment: The problem with your projection method is that you use $\hat{\mathbf{n}} = (1,1,1)$ in the first line and $\mathbf{n} = (-1,-1,1)$ in the fourth instead of the correct $\mathbf{n} = (1,1,1)$. Fix these and you'll get an integral of a constant over $D$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes, I also noticed that. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @MKCCT I replaced my (incorrect) answer with one that just uses the divergence theorem and formulas for areas and volumes of well-known things.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is greatly simplified by noting that the vector field $\mathbf{F} =(y+z)\hat{\mathbf{x}} + (x+z)\hat{\mathbf{y}} + (x+y)\hat{\mathbf{z}}$ can also be written as $\mathbf{F} = (x+y+z)(\hat{\mathbf{x}}+ \hat{\mathbf{y}}+ \hat{\mathbf{z}}) - (x\hat{\mathbf{x}} + y\hat{\mathbf{y}}+ z\hat{\mathbf{z}})$. In terms of the normal vector to the plane $\mathbf{n} = (1,1,1)$, this gives $\mathbf{F} = (\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{x})\mathbf{n} - \mathbf{x}$. Since the original integral is equal to $\iint_S \mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}\, dA$, we have
$$
\iint_S\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}\, dA = \iint_S[(\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{x})\mathbf{n} - \mathbf{x}]\cdot\mathbf{n}\,dA = (n^2-1)\iint_S\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{n}\,dA = 2\iint_SdA,
$$
where for the last equality we have used $\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{x} = 1$ from the definition of $S$ and $|(1,1,1)|^2 = 3$. The remaining integral is just the area of $S$, which is a circle of radius $\sqrt{2/3}$. Thus we have $\iint_S\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}\, dA = 4\pi/3$.

Comment: It should be $\mathbf{\hat{n}}\mathrm{d}A$, so the answer should be divided by $\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: @MKCCT No, the integral you posted is $\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}dA$. If it were $\mathbf{F}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}dA$, there would have been a $1/\sqrt{3}$ in each integrand.

Comment: If it were $\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}\mathrm{d}A$, there would have been $(y+z)\mathrm{d}A+(x+z)\mathrm{d}A+(x+y)\mathrm{d}A$, but $\mathrm{d}A\neq \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Due to symmetry, $I=3\int_S(x+y)dxdy=3\int_D(x+y)dxdy$ where D is the elliptic disk
$$x^2+y^2+xy-x-y\le 0,$$ the projection of $S$ on $xy$-plane. OP also found it. $D$ is parametrized by $-\pi/4\leq\theta\leq 3\pi/4$, $0\leq r\leq r(\theta)=\frac{\sin\theta+\cos\theta}{1+\sin\theta\cos\theta}$. Hence,
$$I=3\int_{-\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}\int_0^{r(\theta)}r^2(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)drd\theta =\int_{-\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}\frac{(sin\theta+cos\theta)^4}{(1+\sin\theta\cos\theta)^3}d\theta=\frac{4\pi}{3\sqrt3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Project the integral onto the $xy$-plane:

$$\begin{aligned}
I &= \iint_S (y+z(x,y),z(x,y)+x,x+y)\cdot \mathrm{d}S\mathbf{\hat{n}} \\
&= \iint_D (y+z(x,y),z(x,y)+x,x+y)\cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}}\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \\
&= \iint_D (1-x,1-y,x+y)\cdot \mathbf{n}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \\
&= \iint_D (1-x,1-y,x+y)\cdot (1,1,1)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \\
&= 2\iint_D\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = 2S_D,
\end{aligned}$$ where $D$ is the projection of $x+y+z=1 \land x^2+y^2+z^2\leq1$ (a circle of radius $\sqrt{2/3}$). Since the cosine of the angle between $x+y+z=1$ and $z=0$ is $1/\sqrt{3}$, the final answer is $2\pi(2/3)\cdot (1/\sqrt{3})=\dfrac{4\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: I saw this 2 too.

Answer (score 0):

Take $$\omega=(xy-xz)dx+(yz-yx)dy+(zx-zy)dz,$$Note that $$d\omega=d\left((xy-xz)dx+(yz-yx)dy+(zx-zy)dz\right)=(y+z)dydz+(x+z)dy+(x+y)dxdy,$$ so you can use Stoke's Theorem to compute the line integral of $\omega$ over your boundary, which is a circle.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your meaning. If we use Stokes' Theorem to calculate that line integral, we would be back to the starting point of the problem.

Comment: It's the Stokes theorem by backwards, not as a volumen integral, a line integral since $\omega$ is a primitive of the $2$-form given to you

Comment: So did you mean computing the line intergral directly? But it seems that the circle does not have a simple parametric equation...

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on the plane $x + y + z = 1$, the integral is the same as
$$I=\iint_S (1 - x)\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z+ (1- y) \mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}x+(1 - z)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y,$$

Since $\iint_S \mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z+  \mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}x+\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$ equals ${\sqrt 3}$ times the area of the circle, which has radius $\sqrt{2 \over 3}$, we get a contribution of ${2 \pi \over \sqrt{3}}$ from this term. So the answer will be
${2 \pi \over \sqrt{3}}$ minus
$$J=\iint_S x\,\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z+ y \,\mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}x+z\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y,$$
The integral $J$ is amenable to the divergence theorem applied to the cone whose vertex is the origin and whose base is $S$. The triple integral coming from the divergence theorem will equal $3$ times the volume of this cone, and the double integral from the conical surface will equal zero since $\langle x,y,z \rangle$ is parallel to the surface.

The volume of the cone readily computed using the fact that the circle is at distance ${1 \over \sqrt{3}}$ from the center of the sphere and has radius $\sqrt{2 \over 3}$. We obtain ${2\pi \over 9} {\sqrt{1 \over 3}}$. Three times this is ${2\pi \over 3 \sqrt{3}}$.

So the overall integral is ${\displaystyle {2 \pi \over \sqrt{3}} - {2\pi \over 3 \sqrt{3}} = {4\pi \over 3\sqrt{3}}}$.